# Laravel 5.6 - update unique attribute

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have a Form Request called JuridicoFormRequest with the method "rules":

```
public function rules() {
  $rules = [
      'rif'=>'required|max:40|unique:juridico,rif',
      'correo'=>'required|max:40|unique:juridico,correo',
      'd_social'=>'required|max:50',
      'r_social'=>'required|max:50',
      'pagina_web'=>'max:40|unique:juridico,pagina_web',
      'capital'=>'required|numeric',
      'fk_lugar'=>'required|integer',
      'fk_lugar_fiscal'=>'required|integer',
      'fk_tienda'=>'integer',
      'num_carnet'=>'max:50'
 ];
 if ($this->juridico){
    $rules['rif'] = 'required|max:40';
    $rules['correo'] = 'required|max:40';
    $rules['pagina_web'] = 'required|max:40';
 }
 return $rules;
}
```

The problem is that in the DataBase, "Correo" attribute must be unique, same for "pagina_web". When I try to update some registry "A" and I write the same "Correo" of another registry "B" or the same "pagina_web" of another registry, throws me an error. This does not happen with the "rif" because is the primary key and I already validated it with:

```
if ($this->juridico) {  /*....*/  }
```

If I do:

```
if ($this->juridico) {  
 $rules['rif'] = 'required|max:40';
 $rules['correo'] = 'required|max:40|unique:juridico,correo';
 $rules['pagina_web'] = 'required|max:40|unique:juridico,pagina_web';
}
```

Throws me the validation message (not an exception) "correo must be unique" while that "correo" and that "pagina_web" is already taken by the registry that I'm updating.

Is there a way to solve this?

**UPDATE:** I solved in this way:

```
public function rules(){

      $rules = [
          'rif'=>'required|max:40|unique:juridico,rif',
          'correo'=>'required|max:40|unique:juridico,correo',
          'd_social'=>'required|max:50',
          'r_social'=>'required|max:50',
          'pagina_web'=>'max:40|unique:juridico,pagina_web',
          'capital'=>'required|numeric',
          'fk_lugar'=>'required|integer',
          'fk_lugar_fiscal'=>'required|integer',
          'fk_tienda'=>'integer',
          'num_carnet'=>'max:50'
      ];


     if ($this->juridico){
        $rules['rif'] = 'required|max:40';
        $rules['correo'] = 'required|max:40|unique:juridico,correo,'.$this->juridico.',rif';
        $rules['pagina_web'] = 'required|max:40|unique:juridico,pagina_web,'.$this->juridico.',rif';
     }

      return $rules;
  }
```

Comment: $rules['correo'] = 'required|max:40|unique:correos',

Comment: I does not work because if I not change "correo" or "pagina_web" while updating, will throws me the validation message "correo must be unique" or "pagina_web" must be unique

Comment: See my post answer

Comment: The rules you are using enforce you to write something different in the field than what's already in the database.

So you'll get a validation error if you type in data that is already in the database. 
That's what it does, is this what you want or ? 
What's the actual use in this application?

Comment: yes but, the registry that I'm updating are already owner of that "correo" and that "pagina_web" , Why it should be different every time I want to update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
]);
```

If your table uses a primary key column name other than id, you may specify the name of the column when calling the ignore method:

```
'email' => Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id, 'user_id')
```

you can customize it!

Answer (score 1):

See documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique

```
$rules['correo'] = 'required|max:40|unique:juridico,correo,pagina_web';
```

or

```
 $rules['correo'] = [
    'required',
    'max:40',
    Rule::unique('juridico')->where(function ($query) use ($paginaWeb) {
       return $query->where('pagina_web', $paginaWeb);
    })
];
```

In AppServiceProvider add this

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('uniq', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        $data = $validator->getData();
        $tableName = $parameters[0];
        unset($parameters[0]);
        $primaryKey = 'id';

        $query = DB::table($tableName);
        // set main uniqueness condition
        $query->where($attribute, '=', $value);
        // if primary key exists - set to NOT be equal (for updating case)

        if (!empty($data[$primaryKey])) {
            $query->where($primaryKey, '!=', $data[$primaryKey]);
        }

        // check conditional columns
        if (!empty($parameters)) {
            foreach ($parameters as $column) {
                if (isset($data[$column])) {
                    $query->where($column, '=', $data[$column]);
                }
            }
        }
        $count = $query->count();
        return ($count == 0) ? true : false;
    });
}
```

and usage

```
$rules['correo'] = 'required|max:40|uniq:juridico,correo,pagina_web';
```

Comment: Sorry but doesn't work for me. Throws me the validation message "correo must be unique" while that "correo" is already taken by the registry that I'm updating. Also my table is called "juridico"

Comment: are you used **required|max:40|unique:juridico,correo,pagina_web**??

Comment: if you updated in your **$data** add **primary-key  => value** pair